# Undefined subroutine &main::timelocal error

Tags: perl, datetime

I have the following error when I execute my perl module :

```
Undefined subroutine &main::timelocal
```

I have defined time and I want in the format of `DDMMYYYY` without any seperators.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer in your description of your requirements. And show some code demonstrating what you have tried.

Comment: Several good answers were given to you.. please show some code already to make it easier to give an answer that fits your actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

To use timelocal like that, you need to import it:

```
use Time::Local 'timelocal';
```

(and make sure you are calling it correctly; see [Time::Local](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aLocal#SYNOPSIS))

But perhaps you meant [localtime](http://p3rl.org/localtime)?  Or you might want [POSIX::strftime](http://p3rl.org/POSIX#strftime).

Comment: i want to implement in localtime only.. if i use like DD/MM/YYYY it is coming.. but my requirement is DDMMYYYY.

Answer (score 2):

You was not very specific where to get the time.  This works for current date, using core [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece) module:

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime->dmy('');    # 05042011
```

If you have time in variable, you can do

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime($time)->dmy('');
```

The empty string in `dmy` call is separator.

Comment: and this Time::piece is not installed in my system.

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using? Time::Piece has been in the standard Perl library since 5.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

The core POSIX module contains a 'strftime' function that handles all of the standard Unix date/time formatting sequences.

```
$ perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le'print strftime "%d%m%Y", localtime'
```

Or, in a program,

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

print strftime '%d%m%Y', localtime, "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

It's an old one but I had this exact error and solved it from looking at the above examples with a different solution.

Reason was that I had not included the ';' at the end of the use statement!

```
use Time::Local ;
```